# Read streamlink m3u8 file using ffmpeg

Tags: python, opencv, debugging, image-processing, ffmpeg

I am using earthcam links for data collection purposes. My implementation works perfectly fine on local but gives me an `OpenCV: image broken error` on CentOS 7 system. As ffmpeg is used in the background for OpenCV, I want to directly use ffmpeg to read m3u8 file retrieved from `streamlink` in the following way.

```
streams = streamlink.streams(stream_link)
q = list(streams.keys())[0]
stream = streams['%s' % q]
video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream.url) ----> # Want to change this line to ffmpeg
```

An example link that I am using in my problem is - [Nyc_5th_Street](https://www.earthcam.com/usa/newyork/fifthave/?cam=nyc5th_str)

Also, In addition, I just need the first frame of the `m3u8` file every time I loop it in.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any Opencv method which allows you to directly access the FFMPEG functionalities. To directly call the FFMPEG routines from your script, you can use [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)

Comment: Thanks @Zdar but this does not seem to be working with m3u8 files. It just throws an error.